# Error when creating Zip file using DotNetZip: Unexpected end of archive

Tags: c#, asp.net, zip, dotnetzip, winrar

I have a method that zips up one or more files using DotNetZip, and it has been working correctly. I received an error for the first time today and it appears to be related to the total size of the archive. Using the same 60mb .tiff image, I would add a few extra copies, test, repeat. It worked fine until about 10 images were added, then, when I opened the Zip file using WinRar, I would get the "Unexpected end of archive" error. Testing in this manner, I believe I've ruled out the problem being related to my code or the files (being corrupt or something). The code does not error, only WinRar. When I open the Zip file, there is only one file displayed with a size of "0." So it seems like some sort of size limit is being reached and it's not allowing the archive to be created. I just don't know which limit it is. Here is my code, if it helps:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "filename=" + "MyFileName" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyy") + ".zip");

using (var zip = new Ionic.Zip.ZipFile())
{
    zip.MaxOutputSegmentSize = 819200; // I tried adding this and it did not fix the problem

    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        zip.AddFile(file.FileLocation, file.ZipFileDirectory).FileName = 
            (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.ZipFileDirectory) && (file.ZipFileDirectory != @"\")) ? 
                string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", file.ZipFileDirectory, file.FileName) : 
                file.FileName;
    }

    zip.Save(HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
}
```

Comment: Does the same happen if you save the zip to a file directly (without using `HttpContext.Current.Response`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need to Flush the stream after your are done writing to it?

`HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();`

**EDIT:**

Call HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()

Comment: .Flush() by itself does not help, however, .End() does. I also tried adding .Flush() before .End() and that works too. I remember using .End() in the past but it was throwing the exception: System.Threading.ThreadAbortException (and it still is now) so I removed it, as it appeared to work fine without it. Do you know why it needs .End() for a large archive yet works fine for smaller archives? If you edit your post to include .End() I'll mark it as the answer - any additional information you can add is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hunting through System.Web, it looks like End() throws a ThreadAbortException if the "handler step" is not Cancellable - if the handler is not IHttpAsyncHandler.    Recommendation on http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629/ is to use HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest() instead.  Can you see if that works?

Comment: In my case HttpContext.Current.Response.End(); worked for both one file archive and large files archive (more than 1400 files).

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer here did not solve the problem for me, however, employing some of the comments led me down the right path. What it took to solve this for me was simply adding

`HttpContext.Current.Response.End();`

after all processing was complete (in my case, immediately after the sample block of code, outside of the using block).