# Creating Zip file with multiple entries

Tags: c#, .net, zip, compression

I'm having trouble creating a zip file with multiple entries. I've looked at the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27098306/c-sharp-create-zip-archive-with-multiple-files) similar question but still no joy. My code is as follows:

```
var folders = await _folderManager.GetDescendentsAsync(id);

using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    // Build the archive
    using (ZipArchive zipArchive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
    {
        foreach (var folder in folders)
        {
            //get the path 
            var path = GetPath(folder);

            foreach (var file in folder.Documents)
            {
                //get the file stream from storage
                var docStream = _documentManager.DownloadById(file.Id);

                //create an entry in the zip
                ZipArchiveEntry archiveEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry(path + file.Name);
                using (var entryStream = archiveEntry.Open())
                {
                    await docStream.CopyToAsync(entryStream);
                }
            }
        }

        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\Temp\ZipFile.zip", FileMode.Create))
        {
            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            await memoryStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
        }
    }
}
```

I get the zip file with multiple entries but am getting the error "Unexpected end of archive" when i try to open it.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: close/flush zip archive *before* saving results with `CopyTo`

Comment: You may need to flush the `memoryStream`, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469434/error-when-creating-zip-file-using-dotnetzip-unexpected-end-of-archive

Comment: Gah! So obvious now but I couldn't see the wood for the trees! I was copying to the fileStream INSIDE the zip archive using statement. By letting the zipArchive dispose, I was able to copy to the file stream. No flushing required.

Answer (score 1):

The [`CopyToAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.copytoasync(v=vs.110).aspx) method copies the contents of one stream to another in chunks. If at the end of the stream the chunk is smaller than chunk size it doesn't always get copied to to the other stream. To fix this you can `Flush` or [`FlushAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.flushasync(v=vs.110).aspx) the `memoryStream`:

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\Temp\ZipFile.zip", FileMode.Create))
{
    memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    await memoryStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);

    await memoryStream.FlushAsync();
}
```

Comment: Still no luck I'm afraid. I've also tried flushing the entryStream after the "await docStream.CopyToAsync(entryStream);" :-(

Comment: @Orbit74 Oh didn't see you were copying there as well, have you tried flushing the `docStream` after it's `CopyToAsync` call?